# Remove the messages tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently stumbled across the mess that is the [messages](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/messages) tag.

It has no followers, which should probably be the main reason for burning a bad tag, as nobody is currently using it to track incoming questions.

It ranges from error messages, the `/var/log/messages` directory, to people putting in `email messages` and accidentally using two tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It's done

I've [retagged](https://serverfault.com/posts/255558/revisions) the last 8 questions. The [messages](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/messages) tag has been purged from SF universe.

Answer (score 9):

Agreed. Since I have a bit of time to kill, I'll start removing the tags from the questions. There's 26 questions with that tag; none of which were asked this year. Once that's done, it'll just disappear from existence.

Comment: Wait, so I can just do it myself? I'll remove some tags tomorrow morning during a quite period then (to save the main page some grief)

Comment: Yeah, just editing the question and removing the tag is enough. I noticed it does kick it to the "Active" tab on the front page, so a quiet period is probably best.

Comment: Somewhere (too lazy to find it now) there's a guideline about only doing about 5 clean-up edits at a time to avoid cluttering /active and the front page.

Comment: @Reaces here the related discussion about it: [What is (or what should be) the etiquette for editing old questions or posts?](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3572/what-should-be-the-etiquette-for-editing-old-questions). Our (ex-)mod also suggest that [we need to keep edits that bump old content to around 2 posts/hour](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/7937/cleanup-duplicate-tags-different-by-hyphenation-and-pluralization#comment17005_7937) so our front page didn't end up like [this case](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6783/mods-robo-rejecting-edits-that-are-objective-improvem)

Comment: Also make sure to retag the question if necessary. I have a sneaky suspicion they were tagged badly to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

That tag needs to go. The word [messages](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/messages) is simply not descriptive enough to be a useful tag name. Tag names such as [email-messages](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/email-messages) and [var-log-messages](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/var-log-messages) may be useful as replacement. At least they are not as ambiguous. But if all the questions in question have other meaningful tags, we could ditch [messages](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/messages) without replacing it with anything.